# Trying to create a Meteor Package

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I've been trying to create a Smart Package for the [SkelJS](http://skeljs.org) framework.
The file is being loaded by the browser but when I try and access the object it exports it says its `undefined`. I'm using the following code in package.js:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "SkelJS for Meteor"
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use('jquery', 'client');
  api.add_files(['skel.js'], 'client');

  api.export('skel', 'client');
});
```

Also trying to access `Package.skeljs.skel` returns `undefined` as well.

In smart.json I'm using:

```
{
  "name": "skeljs",
  "description": "SkelJS for Meteor",
  "homepage": "",
  "author": "Giles Butler  (http://giles.io)",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "git": ""
}
```

I know SkelJS has been loaded because it logs to the console `no configuration detected, waiting for manual init` but then when I try and run `skel.init()` it returns `undefined`.

Any help or tips would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Giles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to modify the first line of `skel.min.js`/`skel.js`

Within packages variable scoping still applies so you have to remove the `var` keyword if you want the file to let other files (such as `package.js` for `api.export`) access its variables.

The fix would be to change:

```
var skel=function() ....
```

to

```
skel=function() ....
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Akshat. I had no idea you had to do that, is that in the docs somewhere as I must have missed it?