# Meteor.js Package: Npm.require cannot find module

Tags: meteor, meteorite, yelp

I'm getting an error in a package I've created called yelp-o-auth. I'm using Meteor version 0.8.3

The error is

```
errorError: Cannot find module 'yelp'
```

This is my code requiring it in yelp-o-auth.js

```
var Yelp = Npm.require("yelp").createClient(auth);
```

This is in package.js

```
Npm.depends({
    'yelp': '0.1.1'
});
```

When I run

```
npm view yelp
```

it returns

```
name: 'yelp',
  description: 'Library for interfacing with Yelp\'s API v2.0.',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '0.1.1' },
  versions: [ '0.1.0', '0.1.1' ],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within packages variable scoping still applies so you have to remove the `var` keyword:

`yelp = Npm.require("yelp").createClient(auth);`

Also, these two related threads may help.

- stackoverflow - [Trying to create a Meteor Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079223/trying-to-create-a-meteor-package)
- Google group - [Error: Cannot find module 'connect'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/Qjs-Jrx1Ygc)

Comment: I mistakenly copied the Npm.require statement into my server.js file and thats what was causing my error. But examining these things are what led me to realize that so thanks.

Comment: ah thanks - good to know the real answer, and sorry I was off-base a little.